# Does this POST and PHP work properly to get input and post to the main server?

Tags: php, html, mysql, input

I finished setting up my static webpage and I set up my apache and mysql, and currently am on the local host. I wanted for a user to input some text, and that text would be put on the actual webpage (for everyone to see). Here is my code:

```
   <div id="1" style="background-image: url('bg1.jpg')>
   <p> Select your location and input your required service </p>
   <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="subject" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
   <h2 style="position:relative;margin-left:550px; color:white;"> Hello 
   World, my name is <?php echo $_POST('subject'); ?> </h2>
```

Basically, did I correctly do this? Will everyone be able to see this, and not just on that computer that posted it? It works on the localhost, but that is just one computer since I do not want to publish and buy a domain until I know it works. I am going to be publishing this page to the web soon and I wanted to make sure that it worked correctly. Also, do those domain providers/internet hosters give a database and something like myphpdomain? I had to use those for this to function properly.

Answer (score 2):

- Just echoing the data received from a form will only print in the machine where the data was submitted.
- To be able to seen by everyone, you have to either use a database or a file in which you have to write the data submitted. In your case, I would suggest, use a MYSQL database or a a simple text file in the server.
- Domain providers provide domains. Get a server space from popular web hosting providers like https://www.godaddy.com/ or 000webhost.com(free) and make the doimain's name servers to point to your server from where you have got the space.
- Most of the hosting providers have phpmyadmin enabled.

Comment: Thank you. Just one more question, I have a database in sql for login info and that works perfectly, but that too is that I made the database inside sql. How do I get this to automatically take that input into the database and publish it for everyone?

Comment: Look at this example, 
[Insert into MySQL using PHP](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp)